# FaceBook App Authentication for Multiple Domains using iframes

Tags: php, facebook, dns

I'm running a number of domains and only want to use one Facebook Application.

I understand the current limitation that you can specify multiple domains but they all must have the same base domain - mine are all different.

Therefore I was considering using an iframe that resides on 1 domain for the Facebook Application Logon. Users would authenticate with this domain and then have logon ability with any or the specified domains. In theory this would work.

I wanted to ask:

- has only one done this before?
- any obvious limitations?
- would this be against Facebook Policies etc?

Only only looking for a facebook logon and a few basic details like name and birthdate.

thankyou

Comment: It won't work.  They set the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header to disallow this.  Google or search SO for "X-FRAME-OPTIONS Facebook"

Comment: thankyou - really helpful in understanding this... thx